# Unable to save data from JSP which is printing in the XML format?

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, flex4

I am retrieving the details from the database and printing them in the XML format. It's working pretty good and can even display the same XML format in the Flex. However, I am not sure, how to save this XML file to give it as a data provider for datagrid.

Here is my JSP code :

<%

```
    ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("select file from file where status='P'");
    rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    out.print("<people>" );         
    while(rs1.next())
    {           
               out.print("<person> " + 
                          "<name>" + rs1.getString(1) +"</name> " + 
                          "</person>") ;      
  }     
   out.println("</people>");
```

%>

It's printing the following details in Flex :

http://localhost:8080/Access/serenity.mp3

I am using the following thing to get the details

event.result.body.people.toXMLString();

Can anyone, pls help me to save the above details in the array collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a [XMLList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XMLList.html) instead of an `ArrayCollection`?

[This article](http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/flex-3-basics-data-grids-with-xml/) has an example on using `XMLList` as a `dataProvider` for a `DataGrid` as well. I hope this helps!